# Extract lines matching listed date & time

Tags: bash, awk, grep, substring, extract

From a time-based data file, I'd like to extract lines matching date & time which are listed in other text file.

From this

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00 0.939646 117.325 89.6035
2020-01-01 00:05:00 1.06663 112.67 90.3349
2020-01-01 00:10:00 1.04123 107.835 91.2749
2020-01-01 00:15:00 1.16821 105.275 91.7174
2020-01-01 00:20:00 1.16821 104.192 91.9994
2020-01-01 00:25:00 0.956576 106.395 91.1905
... (>100000 lines)
```

Extract lines of these date&time

```
2020-01-01 00:15:00
2020-01-01 00:20:00
2020-01-01 01:25:00
2020-01-01 02:30:00
2020-01-02 12:35:00
2020-01-03 01:40:00
2020-01-06 10:45:00
... (>1500 lines)
```

How do I do this with `awk` or `grep`, or something else? I have some experience with `awk` and `grep`, but not a heavy user.

From a comment:

> Initially I tried grep -E "^2020-01-01 00:15:00|2020-01-01
> 00:20:00|....|2021-12-31 00:01:55" data_base.txt, but there are too
> many date&time to extract. Frankly, I tried and it returns grep: out
> of memory. I'm googling with something like 'extract lines matching
> conditions/date and time/etc..', but no result yet.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far, the (incorrect) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output (corresoponding to the sample inputs); in this case it may also be of benefit to know the maximum expected size (MBytes, number of lines) of the input files

Comment: are ***both*** files guaranteed to be sorted in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` order (as shown)? do your input files contain blank lines as shown in the samples?

Comment: Initially I tried `grep -E "^2020-01-01 00:15:00|2020-01-01 00:20:00|....|2021-12-31 00:01:55" data_base.txt`, but there are too many date&time to extract. Frankly, I tried and it returns `grep: out of memory`. I'm googling with something like 'extract lines matching conditions/date and time/etc..', but no result yet.

Comment: try a web search on `awk join files` or `awk merge files`

Comment: And yes, they are sorted in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, as shown. There is no blank lines in the files. The size of input file is ~10MB.

Comment: @markp-fuso `grep  -f` worked for me, but I searched and studied`awk join`, and it looks more useful for further many cases. Thank you for your kindness advices!

Comment: Don't show your attempt in a comment, show it (and everything else) in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -f second_file.txt data_base.txt
```

Comment: It works! It took times, but it works exactly as I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: Add `-F` to speed it up a bit. It'll work with any grep, not just GNU.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{dt=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR{a[dt]; next} dt in a' second_file.txt data_base.txt
```